# FOSS stack for manufacturer-specific vehicle diagnosis, primarily KWP1281 (Audi/VW)

Tags: open-source, car

I am looking for a free and open source vehicle diagnostics tool, or at least a software stack (dongle + library) on top of which such a tool can be built.

There are a bunch of tools out there, mostly for Android, which work with a standard ELM OBD-II reader. However, these are limited to the standardized OBD-II protocols and can only talk to the engine control unit. They do not support any of the vendor-specific protocols (which are needed for anything beyond the OBD-II standard) or any of the other control units.

My main interest is in Volkswagen Group vehicles, which for the most part seem to use KWP1281 as the communication protocol. As I understand, hardware constraints of the ELM OBD-II dongle restrict it to a certain set of protocols, and KWP1281 is not one of them – so I will likely need a different kind of adapter.

Requirements are:

- Support for the KWP1281 protocol (additional KWP2089 support would be even better but is not a must)
- Runs on either Linux or Android
- Dongle connection via Bluetooth or USB
- If it is a library rather than a complete tool, it must be written in C (or possibly a C derivative, e.g. C++ or Objective-C) or Java, or have bindings for at least one of the two languages. (A complete tool can be written in either language.)

Is there anything out there?

Comment: Most of this stuff is proprietary; some leaked, some reverse-engineered. You won't find official data for VW, nor Merc, BMW… etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across a solution:

[kw1281test](https://github.com/gmenounos/kw1281test) is a command-line tool available for Linux, Windows and MacOS. It supports all the operations one would need, such as reading/setting the software coding, reading/saving/testing adaptation values, reading and clearing fault codes and more. It also claims to have limited support for the newer KW2000 protocol, though I have no idea about the limitations.

It requires a USB KKL cable (the same kind that are used for VCDS), which are available for around € 20. On Linux (as well as on MacOS), an additional constraint is that only cables with an FTDI USB-to-serial converter are supported, as the tool needs to send an initialization sequence at a rather exotic 5 bps, then be able to process the response at a different baud rate (mostly 10400 or 9600) within 2 seconds. This is difficult to do reliably with the standard Linux APIs, hence the low-level driver access, though it limits the tool to a particular manufacturer chipset.

A downside is that the tool relies on proprietary drivers from FTDI, rather than the free and functionally equivalent libFTDI. (I have filed a feature request for that.)

It may be difficult to tell from the product description of a USB KKL cable which chip it is based upon. A way around that is to use a RS232 KKL cable behind a separate USB-serial adapter; be sure to get one from FTDI here.

My tries have been successful for the ECUs which actually use KW1281. However, it turns out that many of the ECUs in my car use KW2000, which the tool currently has only limited support for.